# Angularjs Панель навигации в опроснике

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Добрый день! В ангуляре новичок, выполняю такое задание: есть вопросы, у каждого вопроса свой чекбокс, нажав который, в навигации этот вопрос как-то выделяется, допустим, меняется цвет фона. Вот здесь примерно то, что надо:[image: пример] Навигацию хочу сделать как массив ссылок, но у меня пока никаких соображений, как синхронизировать чекбоксы и ссылки в навигации. Я так понимаю, что нужен один общий массив и один пустой массив, в который мы закидываем отмеченные чекбоксы и затем передаём этот массив ссылкам и дальше без понятия, что происходит. Есть какие-то идеи, советы?

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/FzoV2BR14lNcSHLU1kXi?p=preview здесь я пытался совместить чекбокс с ссылкой, создав новую директиву, но при нажимании чекбокса, выделяются все ссылки.

Comment: выделяются все, потому что свойство isChecked - одно на всех

Comment: слишком сумбурное описание, попробуй пойти с описания данных которые у тебя есть и того как ты их хочешь показывать и добавь это в вопрос

Answer (score 0, accepted):

в сервисе массив `data` который используется в обох контроллерах, active_index передаёт индекс выбраного элемента массива из одного контроллера в другой через сервис...

```js
(function() {
  'use strict';
  /*jslint browser:true */
  var my_app;
  my_app = angular.module('my_app', []);
  my_app.service('Environment', ['$http', function($http) {
    var data = [{
      q: '1 + 1',
      a: 2,
      opt: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
      selected: false

    }, {
      q: '2 + 2',
      a: 4,
      opt: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10],
      selected: false
    }, {
      q: '3 + 2',
      a: 5,
      opt: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10],
      selected: false
    }, {
      q: '2 + 1',
      a: 3,
      opt: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10],
      selected: false
    }, {
      q: '5 + 2',
      a: 7,
      opt: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10],
      selected: false
    }, {
      q: '3 + 3',
      a: 6,
      opt: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10],
      selected: false
    }, {
      q: '1 + 5',
      a: 6,
      opt: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10],
      selected: false
    }, {
      q: '6 + 2',
      a: 8,
      opt: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10],
      selected: false
    }], active_index;
    
    this.get_data = function() {
      return data;
    };
    this.set_data = function(val) {
      data = val;
    };
    this.get_active = function() {
      return active_index;
    };
    this.set_active = function(idx) {
      active_index = idx;
    };
  }]);
  my_app.controller('interface_controller', ['$scope', 'Environment', function($scope, Environment) {
    $scope.service = Environment;
    $scope.data = $scope.service.get_data();
    $scope.active_index = $scope.service.get_active();
    $scope.$watch('service.get_active()', function(newVal) {
      $scope.active_index = newVal;
      console.log('$scope.active_index', $scope.active_index);
    });
  }]);
  my_app.controller('navigation_controller', ['$scope', 'Environment', function($scope, Environment) {
    $scope.service = Environment;
    $scope.data = $scope.service.get_data();
    $scope.set_active = function(idx) {
      angular.forEach($scope.data, function(question, index){
        if (index !== idx) {
          question.selected = false;
        }
      });
      $scope.service.set_active(idx);
    }
  }]);
}());
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link data-require="bootstrap-css@3.3.6" data-semver="3.3.6" rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.css" />
  <script data-require="angularjs@1.4.8" data-semver="1.4.8" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.8/angular.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container" ng-app="my_app">
    <div class="row">







      <!--навигация-->
      <div class="col-xs-3" ng-controller="navigation_controller">
        <div class="checkbox" ng-repeat="question in data">
          <label>
            <input type="checkbox" ng-model="question.selected" ng-change="set_active($index)"> {{question.q}}
          </label>
        </div>

      </div>





      <!--панель-->
      <div class="col-xs-9" ng-controller="interface_controller">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
          <!-- Default panel contents -->
          <div class="panel-heading">Panel heading</div>
          <div class="panel-body">
            <!-- List group -->
          <ul class="list-group" ng-repeat="question in data">
            <li class="list-group-item " ng-class="{'active': $index == active_index}">{{question.q}}</li>
            <li class="list-group-item" ng-repeat="val in question.opt">{{val}}</li>
          </ul>
          </div>

          
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Что-то вроде этого нужно?

Comment: было бы не плохо добавить описание, что делает этот код

Comment: ммм ну в сервисе массив который используется в обох контроллерах, `active_index` передаёт индекс выбраного элемента массива из одного контроллера в другой через сервис... Там кода то на 20-30 строчек, остальное декларация массива

Comment: Описание лучше добавить ответ

Comment: Очень близко к тому, что надо, спасибо большое, попробую самостоятельно привести код в нужную форму

Comment: @mandu если что пишите, как смогу отвечу.

Answer (score 1):

Ты можешь сделать по другому.Идея такая,а потом приведу пример

- Навигации храним в массивах.Раз вы так захотели.
- Создаём $scope.answer = {}//для хранения ответов и id навигации(Это будет ключ колонки массива).после заполнения будет выглядеть примерно так $scope.answer = {navigation_id:1, text:'b'}
- Затем вешаем события на них(На навигацию onclick - предполагаю это будет не элемент select,а на input событие onchange)
- При клике на навигацию напишем функцию onTabSelected(navigation_id ),$scope.answer.navigation_id = navigation_id ,что пришлем в функцию.
- Аналогичны действия с input.При событии onchange напишем функцию onAnswerSelected(),где будем проверять на отсутствие значений в $scope.answer
- onAnswerSelected И в этой же функции может делать что угодно

**Реализация:**

```
//Контроллер назовём словно AnswerController.js
$scope.answer = {};
$scope.navigations = [
    'index1.html',
    'index2.html',
    //...
    //...
    'index12.html',
];//храним навигации
```

**HTML**

```
Тут в цикле проходим по навигациям,и в каждой итерации задаём li обработчик передавая ему ключ в mассиве
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="nav in navigations" ng-click="onTabSelected(nav)">{{nav}}</li>
</ul>

при выборе какого либо input а автоматически значение пишется в наш $scop.answer.text = value,И им всем вешаем соответствующий один обработчик

<input type="radio" ng-model="answer.text" value="one" ng-change="onAnswerSelected()" />
<input type="radio" ng-model="answer.text" value="two" ng-change="onAnswerSelected()" />
```

Обратно в наш контроллер AnswerController

```
$scope.onTabSelected = function ( id ) {
    $scope.answer.navigation_id = id;
}

$scope.onTabSelected = function ( id ) {
    $scope.answer.navigation_id = id;
}

$scope.onAnswerSelected = function () {
    //тут проверить на пустоту $scope.answer
    //если все хорошо сделать что то,давайте отправим
    var data = {
        navigation : $scope.navigations[$scope.answer.navigation_id],
        answer     : $scope.answer.text
    };
    $http.post('/someUrl', data, config).then(successCallback, errorCallback);
}
```

Задачу ставил показать ход мысли или подтолкнуть к более лучший реализации ,так что не обессудьте :)
Удачи